# Connecting an external monitor

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, external-display, maintenance

I plan to connect my laptop to a 22" external monitor. My earlier laptop crashed a few days ago because of the video card problem.

I am not an expert in this, but still would like to know connecting an external monitor( I extend the monitor basically) would cause or load my system, and would it eventually cause any problems because of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you should have no problems with it.  My feeling is that your monitor had nothing to do with your old laptop crashing and that it was a hardware fault with your video card.  Sending a second signal out should put no load on your system.

Comment: extending a laptop to a second monitor is extremely common these days.